# Show Hide select options based on previous selection dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, show-hide

Thanks for reading my question... ;-)

I'm building a Wordpress site that uses Custom Posts and Custom Fields to show a vehicle inventory. I would like the visitor to be able to filter the posts by Taxonomies...

The plugin I use for drilling the available Taxonomies (Query Multiple Taxonomies) outputs all options it can find for that particular Taxonomy into a dropdown list.

To prevent the dropdown list (i.e. Model) to become too long, I would like to show only those options that are based on the previous selection.

So when the visitor selects Vehicle = Cars, the dropdown for Manufacturer should only show the car manufacturers.
When the visitor selects a manufacturer, i.e. Ford, the next dropdown for selecting a model should only show the models available for the previous selected manufacturer, in this case Ford...

The labels and level-0 values don't change but when I add or change a manufacturer or model, the level-1 and/or level-2 changes.

Not that important but, if possible, it would also be nice to strip everything not needed to show up in the "filtered" dropdown. In case of the Manufacturer dropdown, level-0 and all the spaces are not needed.
In case of the Model dropdown, level-0, level1 and all the spaces are not needed after selection.

Here's a sample how the HTML-code, generated by the plugin, looks like:

```
<label for="qmt-vehicle">Vehicle:</label>
<select id="qmt-vehicle" name="vehicle">
    <option></option>
    <option class="level-0" value="cars" >Cars</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="motorcycles" >Motorcycles</option>
</select>

<label for="qmt-manufacturer">Manufacturer:</label>
<select id="qmt-manufacturer" name="manufacturer">
    <option></option>
    <option class="level-0" value="cars" >Cars</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="ford" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ford</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="chevrolet" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Chevrolet</option>

    <option class="level-0" value="motorcycles" >Motorcycles</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="honda" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Honda</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="yamaha" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yamaha</option>    
</select>

<label for="qmt-model">Model:</label>
<select id="qmt-model" name="model">
    <option></option>
    <option class="level-0" value="cars" >Cars</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="ford" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ford</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-1-ford" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 1</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-2-ford" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 2</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-3-ford" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 3</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="chevrolet" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Chevrolet</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-1-chevrolet" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 1</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-2-chevrolet" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 2</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-3-chevrolet" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 3</option>    

    <option class="level-0" value="motoren" >Motorcycles</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="honda" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Honda</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-1-honda" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 1</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-2-honda" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 2</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-3-honda" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 3</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="yamaha" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yamaha</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-1-yamaha" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 1</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-2-yamaha" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 2</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-3-yamaha" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 3</option>
</select>
```

I can do some simple things with Javascript but this is not simple to me, sorry... ;-)

Can someone please help me to figure out how to do this in Javascript/JQuery?
Cross browser would be great!

* EDIT ***
The HTML code shows the code send to the browser. Because I cannot modify the plugin that much, I'd like to "manipulate" this code to make it work the way I want to... ;-)
The only fixed things are: Labels for the dropdowns and the Values for all the Class="level-0" elements.

So "Cars" and "Motorcycles" will always stay and never change. BUT from there everything is flexible to change. I.e. when there are no Posts for Chevy's to display, Chevy will not be in the generated HTML. So the plugin only shows dropdown options for the items that are realy there and can be found.
So when there's no Ford available at all, Ford will not be in the dropdown...

I rather not make a predefined list of Manufacurers and their Models.

Answer (score 0):

subscribe to your `select` elements' `onchange` events: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp. In the event handler, read the currently selected value and repopulate the other elements accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you hold the data in javascript so you only need to show the necessary options for each model without having to hide some..

I put this on jsfiddle but the site keeps breaking.
The code below was tested and works though.

Ok Works now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var vehicles = {"Cars": {
            "Ford" : [ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Fusion"], 
            "Chevy": [ "Malibu", "Corvette", "Tahoe"],
            },
 "Motorcycles": {
      "Honda": ["model 1", "model 2", "model 3"],
      "Yamaha": ["model 1", "model 2", "model 3", "model 4"]
    }
};


$(document).ready(function() {
  var $vehiclesList = $("#qmt-vehicle");
  var $manufList = $("#qmt-manufacturer");
  var $modelList = $("#qmt-model");
  var selectedType = null
  var selectedManuf = null;
  $.each(vehicles, function(key, vehicle) {
    $vehiclesList.append($("<option/>", {value:key,text:key}));
  });

  $vehiclesList.bind("change", function() {
    selectedType = $(this).val();
    if (selectedType && vehicles[selectedType]) {
      var manufacturers = vehicles[selectedType];
       $("#qmt-manufacturer option").not(":first").remove();
      $("#qmt-model option").not(":first").remove();
      $.each(manufacturers, function(key, manufacturer) {
         $manufList.append($("<option/>", { value: key, text: key}));
      });
    }
  });

 $manufList.bind("change", function() {
    var selectedManuf = $(this).val();
     $("#qmt-model option").not(":first").remove();
    if (selectedManuf  && vehicles[selectedType] && vehicles[selectedType][selectedManuf]) {
      var models = vehicles[selectedType][selectedManuf];      
      $.each(models, function(key, model) {
         $modelList.append($("<option/>", { value: model, text: model}));
      });
    }
  });

 });
</script>
```

Then in your page you'd have

```
<label for="qmt-vehicle">Vehicle:</label>
<select id="qmt-vehicle" name="vehicle">
    <option></option>

</select>

<label for="qmt-manufacturer">Manufacturer:</label>
<select id="qmt-manufacturer" name="manufacturer">
  <option></option>
</select>

<label for="qmt-model">Model:</label>
<select id="qmt-model" name="model">
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you for taking the time trying to help me out!
I like your solution but I rather have a solution without predefined manufacturers and models, hope you don't mind... ;-)
When I add a vehicle post or model it shows up in the dropdown. So the dropdowns only show what's available, this way searching (filtering) is fast and short listed.
I edited my text and like I said, the only things that are fixed are Cars and Vehicles in the first dropdown. Everything else is related to the vehicles/models entered in the WP-backend as posts.
Manufact/models should not show up when not posted.

Comment: OK sorry I think I skimmed the question and didn't see where you were talking about using a WP plugin that generates this code for you (I thought you had control over the data). It may be possible that you could make your own template of sorts which would convert the data to JSON and then use it the way I did but I'm not familiar with wordpress so I wouldn't know where to start. That being said you could use some of my ideas to remove options from the list.

Comment: Hi Matt ! Thanks for anwering again...;) Yes, the plugin generates this kind of dropdowns for the visitor to filter the posts. Of course I removed the rest of the page, this is only the dropdown part. Like I said, it only shows the vehihles, manufacturers and models that are active in WP. The only certain part is that the first dropdown with cars and motorcycles will always be the same. The rest can vary depending on the entered vehicles. When no Chevy was entered, it will not show in dropdown... I'm not getting any further at this moment, still trying... ;-)

Comment: Hi Matt, Matt I think your solution is very close to what I want exept for the predefined arrays. Isn't it possible, when the page is loaded, to read all the options for each dropdown and put those values into a couple of arrays? Then use these arrays to populate the dropdowns based on prior selection, like you do now with the predefined arrays? Using arrays makes it possible to "re-populated" the dropdowns when the visitor makes different selections... Hope you can help me Matt... ;-)