# Show Hide select options based on previous selection dropdown in Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm building a WordPress site that uses Custom Posts and Custom Fields to show a vehicle inventory. I would like the visitor to be able to filter the posts by Taxonomies...

The plugin I use for drilling the available Taxonomies (Query Multiple Taxonomies) outputs all options it can find for that particular Taxonomy into a dropdown list.

To prevent the dropdown list (i.e. Model) to become too long, I would like to show only those options that are based on the previous selection.

So when the visitor selects Vehicle = Cars, the dropdown for Manufacturer should only show the car manufacturers. When the visitor selects a manufacturer, i.e. Ford, the next dropdown for selecting a model should only show the models available for the previous selected manufacturer, in this case Ford...

The labels and level-0 values don't change but when I add or change a manufacturer or model, the level-1 and/or level-2 changes.

Not that important but, if possible, it would also be nice to strip everything not needed to show up in the "filtered" dropdown. In case of the Manufacturer dropdown, level-0 and all the spaces are not needed. In case of the Model dropdown, level-0, level1 and all the spaces are not needed after selection.

I can do some simple things with JavaScript but this is not simple to me, sorry... ;-)
I searched for tips and examples and tried to make it work but no luck.

Can someone please help me to figure out how to do this in jQuery?

Here is the code,

```
<label for="qmt-vehicle">Vehicle:</label>
<select id="qmt-vehicle" name="vehicle">
    <option></option>
    <option class="level-0" value="cars">Cars</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
</select>
<label for="qmt-manufacturer">Manufacturer:</label>
<select id="qmt-manufacturer" name="manufacturer">
    <option></option>
    <option class="level-0" value="cars">Cars</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="ford">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ford</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="chevrolet">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Chevrolet</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="honda">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Honda</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="yamaha">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yamaha</option>
</select>
<label for="qmt-model">Model:</label>
<select id="qmt-model" name="model">
    <option></option>
    <option class="level-0" value="cars">Cars</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="ford">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ford</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-1-ford">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 1</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-2-ford">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 2</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-3-ford">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 3</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="chevrolet">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Chevrolet</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-1-chevrolet">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 1</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-2-chevrolet">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 2</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-3-chevrolet">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 3</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="motoren">Motorcycles</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="honda">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Honda</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-1-honda">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 1</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-2-honda">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 2</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-3-honda">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 3</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="yamaha">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yamaha</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-1-yamaha">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 1</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-2-yamaha">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 2</option>
    <option class="level-2" value="model-3-yamaha">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Model 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Make your question precise so that we can understand it.  Provide some fiddle or screenshot links to make more readable.

Comment: Where is your attempt? Didn't you see hundred similar questions before posting your own?

Comment: Same as @Praveen, I can understand what you want to ask as whole. But can't understand what you want to achieve precisely. Please make the question clearer.

Comment: You should probably also use the <optgroup> tag instead of trying to create your own pseudo groups using a bunch of non-breaking spaces for indentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210546/show-hide-select-options-based-on-previous-selection-dropdown  - although the older question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use javascript, or jquery.

Here is how I do it.

Get the class that is selected:

```
var levelClass = $('#qmt-manufacturer').find('option:selected').attr('class');
```

Then use the level class to hide or show

```
$('#qmt-model option').each(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    self.hide();
    if (self.hasClass(levelClass)) {
        self.show();
    }
});
```

**Edit**:

to clarify how to use this:
it uses a slightly altered version of the code

```js
$(function(){
    $("#qmt-vehicle").on("change",function(){
        var levelClass = $('#qmt-vehicle').find('option:selected').attr('class');
        console.log(levelClass);
        $('#qmt-manufacturer option').each(function () {
            var self = $(this);
            if (self.hasClass(levelClass) || typeof(levelClass) == "undefined") {
                self.show();
            } else {
                self.hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="qmt-vehicle">Vehicle:</label>
<select id="qmt-vehicle" name="vehicle">
    <option></option>
    <option class="car" value="cars">Cars</option>
    <option class="motorcycle" value="motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
</select>
<label for="qmt-manufacturer">Manufacturer:</label>
<select id="qmt-manufacturer" name="manufacturer">
    <option></option>
    <option class="car" value="cars">Cars</option>
    <option class="car" value="ford">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ford</option>
    <option class="car" value="chevrolet">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Chevrolet</option>
    <option class="motorcycle" value="motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
    <option class="motorcycle" value="honda">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Honda</option>
    <option class="motorcycle" value="yamaha">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yamaha</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, good solution. I only need to know if this solution is cross-browser.

Comment: It is jquery, so yes it is cross browser

Comment: When changing in the main SELECT, how can I reset the second one? I mean, if the second select has a selected item, when change the first select, although elements inside change, the main text do not.

Comment: I mean that in case I have two dropdown list, the first for Manufacturer and the second for the Model, when I select a new manufacturer, the content in the second dropdown updates but the text not. I have two browse the dropdown list to select another and update the text instead of select the first one by default.

Comment: 'but the text not' -> what text? please create a jsfiddle or something so I can look at your code

Comment: @Apalabrados I added a snippet which shows the way this code works

Comment: Can this be expanded so that a order code is displayed depending on the combinations of choices? @danielTulp

Answer (score 0):

A Javascript might help you...
You can add an "`onchange`" event (in Javascript) in your "`select`" component. Also, add an `ID` for the `labels`.

Example:

```
<label for="qmt-manufacturer" id="lblManufacturer">
<select id="qmt-manufacturer" name="manufacturer" 
                   onchange="changeManufacturer(this.value);">
```

Using a `script` tag, build your method in javascript as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeManufacturer(manufacturerValue){

         switch(manufacturerValue){
          case ford:
             document.getElementById('lblManufacturer').innerHTML = 'FORD';
             break;
          case chevrolet:
             document.getElementById('lblManufacturer').innerHTML = 'Chevrolet';
             break;
         }

         // And so on for other values...
    }
</script>
```

this code above changes the Label Text running time, implement it to make changes in your second `dropdown` (Model)

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to achieve this --- Check this Fiddle example: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z53JM/)

You can learn from this example and add according logic which you need for the third option box.

jQuery Code:

```
$('#qmt-vehicle').on('change', function () {
//alert(this.value); // or $(this).val()
if (this.value == 'cars') {
    $("#qmt-manufacturer").html(
        "<option class=\"level-1\" value=\"ford\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ford</option><option class=\"level-1\" value=\"chevrolet\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Chevrolet</option>");

} else {

    $("#qmt-manufacturer").html(
        "<option class=\"level-1\" value=\"honda\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Honda</option><option class=\"level-1\" value=\"yamaha\">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Yamaha</option>");
}

});
```