# How to make select appear one after one in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am new in JS and I need some help. I want my 2-nd selectto appear only if the first one is already chosen, the 3-th select to appear after the second choise is done and the submit button to appear after the third choise is done.Is it possible to do that using a loop ?

```
    <style>
      select{float:left}
       #month,#day,input{display:none} 
  </style>


  <select required id='year' class='selectOption' onchange='select(this)'>
      <option value=""> Select year</option>
      <option value="">2016</option>
      <option value="">2015</option>
      <option value="">2014</option>
      <option value="">2013</option>
      <option value="">2012</option>
      <option value="">2011</option>
      <option value="">2010</option>
      <option value="">2009</option>
      <option value="">2008</option>
      <option value="">2007</option>


    </select>
    <select required id='month' class='selectOption' onchange='select(this)'>
      <option value=""> Select month</option>
      <option value="">January</option>
      <option value="">February</option>
      <option value="">March</option>
      <option value="">April</option>
      <option value="">May</option>
      <option value="">June</option>
      <option value="">July</option>
      <option value="">August</option>
      <option value="">September</option>
      <option value="">October</option>
      <option value="">November</option>
      <option value="">December</option>
    </select>
    <select required id='day' class='selectOption' onchange='select(this)'>
      <option value="">Select Day</option>
      <option value="">1</option>
      <option value="">2</option>
      <option value="">3</option>
      <option value="">4</option>
      <option value="">5</option>
      <option value="">6</option>
      <option value="">7</option>
      <option value="">8</option>
      <option value="">9</option>
      <option value="">10</option>
      <option value="">11</option>
      <option value="">12</option>
      <option value="">13</option>
      <option value="">14</option>
      <option value="">15</option>
      <option value="">16</option>
      <option value="">17</option>
      <option value="">18</option>
      <option value="">19</option>
      <option value="">20</option>
      <option value="">21</option>
      <option value="">22</option>
      <option value="">23</option>
      <option value="">24</option>
      <option value="">25</option>
      <option value="">26</option>
      <option value="">27</option>
      <option value="">28</option>
      <option value="">29</option>
      <option value="">30</option>
      <option value="">31</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" class='selectOption'> 

   </form>
```

```
 function select(par) {
    var i = 0;
     var x = document.getElementsByClassName('selectOption');
      if (par.selectedIndex !== "0" && i<x.length) {
        x[i++].style.display = 'block';    
       } 
  }

 </script>
```

Comment: Drop Down Lists that are depending on each are called Cascading Drop Down Lists. You should be able to find tons of resources and tutorials on how to do so looking for that term. Regarding visibility, setting in css visibility to hidden or visible will do the trick. (Display: none; Display block; would work as well)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Hide select options based on previous selection dropdown in Jquery or Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579532/show-hide-select-options-based-on-previous-selection-dropdown-in-jquery-or-javas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by hiding all select but the first one on page load and displaying them one by one after selecting the previous select.

```
 <select required id='month' class='selectOption hide' onchange='select(this)'>

 <select required id='day' class='selectOption hide' onchange='select(this)'>
```

plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/oKwq0q4IB5poKuUOa6oG?p=preview

Define your function like this.

```
function select(par) {
  if (par.selectedIndex !== 0) {
    par.nextElementSibling.className = "selectOption";
   } 
}
```